# returning a set of keys in the map matching the criteria

Tags: c++, stl

First I will give a specific case, and the I would like to see if it can be applied to a general problem.

Say I have map. And I want to get all the keys meeting a certain criteria.
For example all keys that contain "COL". My naive implementation will be

```
template<typename T>
void  Filter (map<string, T> & m, std:set<string> & result, const std::string& condition)
{
    for(map<string,string> iter=m.begin();iter!m.end();iter++)
    {
           std::string key=iter->first; 
           size_t found=key.find(condition);
           if (found!=string::npos)
              result.insert(key);
    }     

}
```

what is the good way to implement this?

Also, what is a good way to implement general problem when I want to filter map using algos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is rather good: it is clear, and except if you can "guess" hash values based on the condition, I don't think you could be much more performant. However, you could change your function to make it more generic:

```
template<typename TKey, typename TValue, typename Predicate>
void filter (const map<TKey, TValue> & m, 
             set<TKey> & result, 
             Predicate & p)
{
    typename map<TKey,TValue>::const_iterator it = m.begin();
    typename map<TKey,TValue>::const_iterator end = m.end();

    for( ; it != end ; ++it)
    {
        TKey key = it->first;
        if (p(key))
            result.insert(key);
    }     
}
```

Your example can then be writen using a functor as predicate:

```
struct Contains {
    Contains(const string & substr) : substr_(substr) {}

    bool operator()(const string & s)
    {
        return s.find(substr_) != string::npos;
    }

    string substr_;
};
```

The call to filter will then look like this:

```
map<string, Obj> m;
// Insert in m
set<string> res;
filter(m, res, Contains("stringToFind"));
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a candidate for `remove_copy_if`. I've written something using `boost` that probably looks more than disgusting, but provides a generalization of your algorithm.

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct filter_cond : std::unary_function<std::string, bool> {
    filter_cond(std::string const &needle):needle(needle) { }
    bool operator()(std::string const& arg) {
        return (arg.find(needle) == std::string::npos);
    }
    std::string needle;
};


int main() {
    std::set<std::string> result;
    typedef std::map<std::string, int> map_type;
    map_type map;

    std::remove_copy_if(
        boost::make_transform_iterator(map.begin(),
                                       boost::bind(&map_type::value_type::first, _1)),
        boost::make_transform_iterator(map.end(),
                                       boost::bind(&map_type::value_type::first, _1)),
        std::inserter(result, result.end()), 
        filter_cond("foo")
    );
}
```

I would probably prefer the manual loop. C++1x will make look that really much better with lambda expressions.

Comment: I tried to implement this not using boost and failed. I mean just remove_copy_if and inserter. Any ideas?

Comment: hmm you would need to code your own input iterator wrapper i think. i can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: another idea may be to use transform, and return an empty string in case of rejection. but that's ambiguous if the needle is an empty string too :(

Comment: Sasha, that depends on whether or not you already use boost in your project and what the filter condition is. Sometimes you can get away with not writing an own functor too (string::find is overloaded so it doesn't work nicely with boost::bind taking its address).

Answer (score 0):

> what is the good way to implement this?

Take a look below. This is untested stuff though so you may need to fix it.

```
/* return some value */
/* fix order of input and output instead of having them mixed */
template<typename T>
size_t Filter(map<string, T> m, 
             string const& condition /* fixed condition; mark it as such */
             set<T>& result /* reference to add efficiency */
             )
{
  typename map<string, T>::const_iterator last = m.end();
  typename map<string, T>::const_iterator i = find_if(m.begin(),
                                             last,
                                             bind2nd(equal(), condition)
                                            );
  while (i != last) {
       result.insert(*i);
       i = find_if(i + 1,
                   last,
                   bind2nd(equal(), condition)
                   );
  }
  return result.size();
```

}

> Also, what is a good way to implement general problem when I want to filter map using algos?

Take a look at [`std::transform`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/transform.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, some very minor suggestions:

- You could cache the value of m.end()
- You could use `++iter`, which saves you one copy of the iterator
- You could improve clarity by moving the test to a very explicitely named function like ''KeyContainsSubstring(const std::string&)'' or similar.

On the more general handling of this sort of tasks, I tend to actually prefer explicit loops like you did. std::map does not provide a more efficient keys iteration mechanism anyway.

Alternatives would include [`std::for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each.html) coupled with [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/bind/bind.html), or [`boost::lambda`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/lambda.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
template<class T>
struct StringCollector
{
public:
    StringCollector(const std::string& str, std::set<std::string>& selectedKeys) : m_key(str), m_selectedKeys(selectedKeys)
    {

    }

    void operator()(const std::pair<std::string,T>& strPair_in)
    {
        size_t found = strPair_in.first.find(m_key);
        if(found != std::string::npos)
        {
            m_selectedKeys.insert(strPair_in.first);
        }
    }

private:
    std::set<std::string>& m_selectedKeys;
    std::string m_key;
};
```

In the calling code:

```
std::set<std::string> keys;
StringCollector<int> collector("String",keys);
std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), collector);
```